# How to stop loading effect after generating PDF in javaScript?

Tags: javascript

How to stop loading message after PDF or Excel sheet is Generated?

My Code is given below:

1st Process:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#page_effect').fadeIn(2000);
    var check = $('#loadcheck').val();
    alert(check);
    if(check == "true"){
     hide Waiting Page()
   }
});
```

2nd Process:

```
 setTimeout(function(){
  window.location.href = window.location.href;
 },36000)
```

1st Process:

unhide the Loading effect immediately before generating the PDF while

2nd process:

took 36000 millisecond but my requirement is i want to display loading message till my jasper report or Excel sheet is loaded and after loading the data i want to stop display loading in my JSP page.

Comment: You seem to write code in JavaScript, but your title contains Java. That are different languages.

Comment: when is the event which triggers the request for pdf generation fired? Where do you have that code written? There yo got to display the loading icon and when you recieve data, you got to hide the icon. Can you show that call/code?

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to stream your report to a containing DOM element in your JSP after it has been generated (no file downloads here), you can easily just have a jQuery handler that will perform the task for you when a button or link is clicked.

```
$("#showDataButton").on('click', function(e) {
  $.ajax({
    beforeSend: function(options) {
      $("#waitingIndicator").show();        
    },
    success: function(data) {
      $("#waitingIndicator").hide();
    }
  });
});
```

If you are wanting the contents downloaded via a PDF as your question indicates, then this gets to be a tad more trickier.

Because browsers do not trigger an event when a file begins to download from a server, your only via option that I know of is to resort to using IFRAMEs.

The idea is that you post your form via javascript to the IFRAME and have the IFRAME perform the download stream for you.  This allows your main window to continue doing it's thing.  When you post the form, your start a timer that checks the contents of the downloaded IFRAME every few milliseconds.

When your IFRAME downloads the file, it should be sent a COOKIE from the server that indicates the download succeeded or failed.  The timer callback from the main window uses this to determine when to hide your waiting message or inform you of some error.

There are some jQuery plugins that exist for this sort of handling so you may want to investigate whether they work for your case.

Comment: I have tried your code but it is refreshing the page before the PDF or 
Excel generation. To generate PDF i am using Jasper Report so when i click on Print button it is opening new window to generate  PDF and my requirement is showing loading message in existing window and after generating pdf in new window i have to refresh the existing window to unhide Loading... effect